# Zip files created with Delphi TZipfile on a windows platform not portable to other OS

Tags: delphi, zip, compatibility

I have written a Zip utility using Delphi which zips a directory tree but includes only files of certain types. The objective is to create a utility that will create a zip package of files to be sent for processing remotely.

With my first attempt I was able to create a zip file and extract the full directory tree on a windows platform, but they were not being processed when sent to the remote system.  I discovered that when viewed or extracted on IOS the zip file seemed to loose the directory structure and I suspect this is the problem.

After some research on Stack overflow and the web I replaced backslash with a forward slash in the directory path.  This made no difference.  The directory structure and still file extracted perfectly on windows, but not on IOS, nor will it extract on an Amazon platform where these files will ultimately be processed automatically.

The code I am using to add files with a matching file extension is below.  What am I missing here - what is the secret to creating fully portable zip files?

```
procedure TFORM2.FileSearch(Zip: TZipFile; const PathName: string; RootPos: Integer);
const
  FileMask = '*.*';
  Extensions = '.csv,.xml,.txt,.jpg'; // File types we want to zip
var
  Rec: TSearchRec;
  Path: string;
  FromPath, ToPath: String;
begin
  Path := Trim(IncludeTrailingBackslash(PathName));
    if FindFirst(Path + FileMask, faAnyFile - faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
      try
        repeat
        if AnsiPos(ExtractFileExt(Rec.Name), Extensions) > 0 then
          Begin
            FromPath := Path + Rec.Name ;
            ToPath   := copy(Path, RootPos, path.Length - rootpos + 1) + Rec.Name;;
            ToPath   := StringReplace(ToPath,'\','/',[rfReplaceAll]);
            Zip.Add(FromPath, ToPath);
            File_Count := File_Count + 1
          End;
        until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
        Except
        on E:EZipException do
          Begin
            ShowMessage('Exception: ' + E.Message);
          End;
        End;
      FindClose(Rec);
    if FindFirst(Path + '*.*', faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
      try
        repeat
        if ((Rec.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0) and (Rec.Name <> '.') and
          (Rec.Name <> '..') then
          FileSearch(Zip, Path + Rec.Name, RootPos);
        until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
      Except
        on E:EZipException do
        Begin
        ShowMessage('Exception: ' + E.Message);
        End;
      end;
      FindClose(Rec);
    End;
```

Comment: There's more code than needed here. Simplify. You should be able to construct a minimal example that doesn't include any file find code, any extension matching code. Just needs to ZIP a hard coded path of perhaps just a single file. Provide that [mcve] and hopefully it will become clear. Probably clear to you also.

Comment: You shouldn't be using IncludeTrailingBackslash, because it's not cross-platform. Use IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter. You haven't indicated what is actually happening, e.g. example values for FromPath and ToPath. As David has indicated, the example is not complete. For example, there's no code to show what the filename is that is passed to the Open method of TZipFile, and whether or not the Close method is even being called.

Comment: In fact, zip directories should always use forward slash as path separator, see [pkzip spec](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) 4.4.17.1